# Cloning Azure git repository reports "could not resolve host"

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

Here is my git url as reported by Azure TFS:

```
https://mycompany@dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_git/myproject
```

Here is my clone command

```
git clone https://myusername:mypass@mycompany@dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_git/myproject
```

However, I am unable to access the repository. The error is:

```
Could not resolve host: mycompany@dev.azure.com
```

Can someone please suggest how to overcome this? Regards.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or do you have to route all traffic through a proxy?

Comment: You cannot pass 2 logins. It's either `myusername:mypass@dev.azure.com` or `mycompany:companypass@dev.azure.com` but not both.

Comment: phd. Thank you for your hint. Turns out Azure generated url is somewhat incorrect. It should really be https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/xxx.

Comment: You could also install the latest version of git credential manager https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.18.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was from the hint in phd's comment. Turns out, Azure generated url is somewhat misleading. Instead of,

```
 https://mycompany@dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_git/myproject
```

it should really be:

```
https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_git/myproject
```

This way, the following would work:

```
https://myuser:mypass@dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_git/myproject
```

Answer (score 6):

maybe you dont have internet connection. you can check connection.