# Could not resolve host: dev.azure.com while cloning a git repository

Tags: azure-devops

I am getting below error while cloning a git repository from azure devops
URL : https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_git/myproject
ERROR : Could not resolve host: dev.azure.com

i am trying via Git CMD and VS Code.
Both is not working.

I also tried using the token which we get in azure repo.

I unset all the proxy now, becuase i was getting HTTP403 error while clone before.

NOTE : The proxy which i used was fom my organisation. And now iam doing this as a sample project with my personal gmail id in azure devops.

Thanks,
Chithra

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712941/cloning-azure-git-repository-reports-could-not-resolve-host

Comment: I have seen this. Also tried this.Still same issue

Answer (score 4):

If you were working behind a corporate proxy. You can try registering your company's proxy in your git config using below command.

`git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:port`

You can try running below command

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy 
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370294/could-not-resolve-host-github-com-error-while-cloning-remote-repository-in-git) for more information.

Comment: Now i am geeting an error after setting the proxy:  Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT

Comment: It looks like a permission issue of access the repo. Did it prompt you for password? Try using git url `https://mycompany@dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_git/myproject` , Or try providing credentials for your azure repo while git cloning. Use `youruser:password` or `PAT` in the git clone url. eg. `git clone https://PAT@dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_git/myproject`, Or use SSH url instead of HTTP

Comment: Hi @chithra How was it going?

Comment: Yes, i used this syntax only. Is there any issue with my PROXY then?Becuase i can clone my git repos using that proxy. Only issue while cloning azure repo

Comment: Which syntax you have used. Did it prompt you for password. You can try using the credential generated by clicking the `Generate Git Credentials` when you click the `clone` button to get the clone url on azure devops repo